# Add datastore filter on top of scheduler filter openstack

Tags: vmware, openstack, vmware-clarity, openstack-nova

I was going through scheduler filter docs. https://docs.openstack.org/nova/latest/user/filter-scheduler.html
Here's my understanding about how filters-scheduler work.
When we set the filter schedulers, based on filters it finds the most appropriate host which fullfills all the criteria mentioned by filters.
The above filters works fine, but:

I want to extend the filter's capabilities by first checking if a datastore meets particular criteria, and then check for other filters.
Is this possible? Can we write our own filter in such a way that it will first filter the datastore based on `datastore_regex` and then apply another filter?

Comment: You understanding is not quite correct. Filters don't find the best fit, they generate a list of hosts that are able to run the instance. Finding the best compute host is done in the weighting step.

Comment: You should be able to call filters from other filters, but I think your scenario can be addressed by having your datastore filter at the head of the enabled_filter list (https://docs.openstack.org/nova/latest/user/filter-scheduler.html#configuring-filters).